# Backing up LVM volume with multiple partitions

Tags: linux, lvm, rdiff-backup, kpartx

I want to create  a backup of a LVM volume (Xen DomU's), however a LVM volume can have multiple partitions and those are dynamic (I cannot guarantee LVM #1 has 1 partition and LVM #2 has 3 etcetera).

I'm using `kpartx` to mount a LVM volume, however it will create multiple mappings (1 for each partition + 1 swap) and I want to use `rdiff-backup` to backup the volume. But as I don't know how many partitions a volume has I cannot rely on this.

Now my question is: is there any way to let kpartx map all partitions but within the same "file"? For examply only `/dev/mapper/lvm1` instead of `/dev/mapper/lvm1`, `/dev/mapper/lvm2`, `/dev/mapper/lvm3` `/dev/mapper/lvm5` (1 to 3 are partitions and 5 is swap).

I need this to use `rdiff-backup` to backup and restore a complete LVM volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is short: No - there in no way to let kpartx map all partitions but within the same "file"?

Remark: `kpartx` does not mount anything, it creates device maps.

From your questions it is not clear if the domu is running when the backup should be done. Therefore it's hard to give any further advice.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if it would be possible for you to take another approach and use [guestfish](http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html) for accessing the domU file system(s).

Comment: +1; I have used guestfish for doing exactly this, in the service of our gradual migration from xen to kvm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fsarchiver to backup your lvm. You can start from here http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart

Comment: I'd rather not archive it. As I cannot use `rdiff-backup`, I need to see all individual files, archiving it will only create one (big) file.