# rsync incremental history

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to create a backup of a LVM volume and I have a simple `img` file which contains all data. Is there any way to have this have incrementally backed up using rsync? Like a full backup every week, then each consecutive day an incremental backup until the full backup is again.

I'd like let's say restore to the backup made on Wednesday (similar as `rdiff-backup` can do, but `rdiff-backup` only support multiple files).

So: is it possible with `rsync` to have full and incremental backups and destroy the oldest (using a weekly 'rotation'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to incrementally backup the whole `.img` file? In that case: No, it's not possible with rsync.

To do that, you could use a file system that supports efficient snapshots, like Btrfs or ZFS, or try to use [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/).

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. I'm currently mounting the volume but then there could be multiple partitions, see: http://serverfault.com/questions/369147/backing-up-lvm-volume-with-multiple-partitions/369178. However shame it doesn't work then. :-( Do you have any other idea how it could work? Using ext3 and ntfs partitions?

Comment: I have a fundamental problem with your image file approach and would rather backup separate files.

Comment: What would you do then? I do not own the LVM volumes on the disk (as they are used for virtual machines) so I cannot install anything on the virtual machine, therefore I need an "external" approach.

Comment: I would back it up like any physical machine. In most cases, this means separate backup of the boot sector, details about the partition table and of course, the backups of the file on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any open source tool which can do efficient incremental backups of large files. [BUP](https://github.com/apenwarr/bup) might be worth keeping an eye on, but beware the warnings. I believe there are several commercial backup applications that are designed for external backup of VM images (implying that, if they are worth anything, that they support efficient incremental backups of images), but I have no personal experience of any of those.

Comment: Do you know any commercial product to use with Xen (LVM)?